# Marking text in the row of the list as "READ" permenatly Android

Tags: android, listview, onclick

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to set the text in a given row as read if the user clicks on it, now I was able to do that by using the onclick method, the problem with it is that it goes away when an intent is fired or the user exits the app. I want the Text to be set up as read permanently. here is my piece of code if anybody can help I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you in advance:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v;
  TextView clickedTextView = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(1);
  clickedTextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strings[position],"<@>");
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    coupon = st.nextToken("<@>");
  }
  sharable=st.nextToken();
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CouponImage.class);
  i.putExtra("The coupon", coupon);
  i.putExtra("Sharable", sharable);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to store the read status for each text item, either in a [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), or in a flat file in [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is because whenever you scroll the list, leave the app and come back, etc. you end up with the ListAdapter re-rendering your row view, and your views in a list are never 1:1 with underlying data due to view recycling. If you want your change to be "sticky" you need to think about modifying the underlying data for the ListAdapter in a way it the adapter knows how to render correctly, not just changing this particular instance of a row -- you're *marking the item* read, not just *setting one instance of a rendered view of the item* as read. You can think of it as an MVC thing if it helps.

That is, the real change here should be to your Adapter's [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) method, with a change to its data source and then possibly a call to [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Fredley's answer about SQLite or storage may be overkill if that data doesn't need to persist beyond this one session in the activity, or if the data you're working with is also transient (e.g. network data that changes often that's temporarily loaded into an ArrayAdapter), and in any case it's a bit misleading because just dumping data to disk doesn't solve the fundamental issue with your conflation of *views of data* with *your models*.

Comment: *or the user exits the app* - I would say it does need to persist over multiple sessions.

Comment: I tried your solution and it's not giving a result can anyone please give me a solution preferably someone who was able to achieve it and if possible some code to make things a lot clearer.